# Using recursion in bubble sort

Tags: c++, algorithm

Hello everyone I am starting to learn Data structures and Algorithms and implemented bubble sort myself after learning the concept. Following is the code I have written with my understanding but the problem is it runs for only one cycle and does not sort recursively.

- For example:

{ 5,1,4,2,8} is sorted one time ->  {1,4,2,5,8,}

What can be the problem?

```
vector<int> bubble_sort(vector<int> vec){
 int temp = 0;

 for(int i = 0; i < vec.size()-1; i++){    
      temp = vec.at(i+1);                    // holds the adjacent element.

// the following loop swaps the adjacent elements if the previous one is big
            if(vec.at(i) > vec.at(i+1)){
                      vec.at(i+1) = vec.at(i);
                      vec.at(i) = temp;
            }     
           temp = 0;
      }


 for(int i = 0; i < vec.size()-1; i++){         
        if(vec.at(i) > vec.at(i+1)){
            bubble_sort(vec);  
        }     
  }

return vec;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function takes a `vector<int>` vector by copy, hence after first swaps only this copy is send to recursively sort.

Just add `&` to your function parameter: `vector<int> bubble_sort(vector<int> &vec)` and it should work

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement recursion fully and do not want to use for loop in the code, then follow this example. It will be helpful.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
/* Function to print an array */
void printArray(int arr[], int n)
{
    for (int i=0; i <= n; i++)
        cout<<arr[i];
}

void bubble_sort_recursive(int arr[], int j, int n) {
   
   // base case 
    if (n==0 || j>n){
        return;
    }
    
    // single pass has been completed and the higher element moved to right for that subarray
    // now call the recursive function by keeping aside the already sorted positioned element
    //i.e next pass wil start from this call
    if (j == n){
            bubble_sort_recursive(arr,0,n-1);
    }

    // swap consecutive 2 elements - main basic of bubble sort
    if (arr[j]>arr[j+1]){
        int t = arr[j];
        arr[j] = arr[j+1];
        arr[j+1] =t;
    }
    // go forward for next element of a single pass
    bubble_sort_recursive(arr,j+1,n);
}


int main() {
    int arr[] = {5,4,3,2,1};
    // get the length of array
    int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    // call from 0 to len-1 as index starts from 0
    bubble_sort_recursive(arr,0,n-1);
    // print the sorted array
    cout<<"Sorted array:"<<endl;
    printArray(arr, n-1);
}
```